# javascript style with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I cannot figure out how can I style element with JavaScript style property

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#element {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="element"></div>
</body>

<script>
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w_center = w/2;
    var h_center = h/2;
    var element = document.getElementById("element");

    element.style.left = w_center;
</script>
</html>
```

the proper way of styling with JavaScript is

```
    element.style.left = "100px";
```

the value after the equal sign must be quoted, but if I use double quotation with variable it doesn't work because it will be converted to string.

so I tried

```
<script>
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w_center = String(w/2);
    var h_center = String(h/2);
    var element = document.getElementById("element");

    element.style.left = w_center;
</script>
```

I tried to use "String()" function to convert the "w_center" to string, but still doesn't work

is there any other way I could use the variable as my value using the code below?

```
element.style.left = w_center;
```

yes I can do jQuery way like $("#element").css("left", w_center) it works but I want to use javascript.

Regards.

Comment: what are you trying to do here bro?

Comment: element.style.left = String(math.round(w_center)) +"px";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `+"px"` to the end of the number and it will be converted to a string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#element {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:red;/* I added this for visual reasons */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="element"></div>
<script>
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    var w_center = w/2;
    var h_center = h/2;
    var element = document.getElementById("element");
    element.style.left = w_center+"px";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Ultimater! it was this simple :)